# How to redirect web form authentication after authentication in J2EE

Tags: java, html, tomcat, authentication, servlets

I search for a while for a way to create a web form base authentication for my web site. I'm using tomcat to run the web server.

I found this http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-form-authentication-with-tomcat.html?page=1

and some youtube videos that show basically the same, you can set a login page and an error page in `web.xml` inside `WEB-INF`:

```
<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/login-failed.html</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

in case the login successful you send from the `servlet` dynamic code:

for an example:

```
out.print("</em>, Header Value: <em>" + headerValue);
out.println("</em>");
```

I'm looking for a way to have authentication for user and password, after this done, i want to be able to show another page afterLogin.html.

is there any good way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on what you want, I would simply say that you just need to do the following after successful authentication:

```
response.sendRedirect(afterLogin.html);
```

This will direct to the page that you want to display after the login was successful.

Hope this helps,

Let me know of the outcome.

Comment: wow, simple as that ha ? :), in case I would want to make this page restricted only for authorized users I have to create a rule in the XML file right?

Comment: Hi I would suggest you use a session object or maybe cookies for that regard. So you first check if either of those are active. If they are you allow the use access, else you ask them to log in. If the authentication is correct then simply create a new session or cookie that will inform your application that they are authorized and then you redirect them to the secure page. Else you send them back to the authorization page. This will all happen in your Servlet ... Also your IDE will automatically configure the XML page accordingly

Comment: Not a problem at all. If you require help with that, post another question, and I will answer it accordingly. Good luck!